# How to get just integers out of a textfield in js?

Tags: javascript, html, input, textfield

So I wanna get just integers out of a html input and  work with it in js.

```js
function apply(){
    let input = document.getElementById("txtfield").value;
    console.log(input);
    document.getElementById("txtfield").value = '';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <title>stack qustion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <input id="txtfield">
  <button onclick="apply()" id="apply">apply</button>                              
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `type="number"` to your input field so that the user can only type numbers:

`<input type="number" id="txtfield">`

Or if you only want to get the integers out and still be ably to type other characters into to text field. Then you have to add a check to your function. This regular expression `input.replace(/\D/g,'')` will remove all non-numeric characters from the input string :

```js
function apply(){
    let input = document.getElementById("txtfield").value;
    console.log(input.replace(/\D/g,''));
    document.getElementById("txtfield").value = '';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <title>stack qustion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <input id="txtfield">
  <button onclick="apply()" id="apply">apply</button>                              
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrong for `wfewfwe44d`

Comment: I have updated the regular expression. This one should work for `wfewfwe44d`

Answer (score 0):

Use `regex` to replace all non-numeric values:

```js
function apply(){
    let input = document.getElementById("txtfield").value;
    console.log(input.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ''));
    document.getElementById("txtfield").value = '';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <title>stack qustion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <input id="txtfield">
  <button onclick="apply()" id="apply">apply</button>                              
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```